# Need to generate a 2D python list with each column having 2 possibilities, for each row

Tags: python, list

I need to generate a two-dimensional python list. It would consist of 10 columns, with each column value being either '1' or '0'. Given these conditions, my list needs to be an exhaustive list of all the combinations that can be formed in this way. It'd naturally end up being 1024 rows long (2^10). However, I have no clue where to get started on this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You could use the binary representation of all the numbers from 0 to 1023. That doesn't sound too difficult.

Comment: Try looking at the numpy.random.permutation function. More info here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how I worked through this problem. First I saw that we wanted to loop over all 1024 combinations of 0s and 1s. This is essentially counting from 0 to 1023 in binary. So I made a `for` loop from 0 to 1023 and at each iteration, I converted the iteration variable `i` into binary with `format(i, 'b')` and then turned it into a list with the `list` method. In the case of a number like 1, this gets converted into `['1']` but we want to convert that into `['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']` which is what line 
4 does. Finally, we append each result into the 'table' variable.

```
table=[] 
for i in range(1024):
     binaryRepresentation = list(format(i, 'b'))
     finalRepresentation = ['0']*(10-len(binaryRepresentation)) + binaryRepresentation
     table.append(finalRepresentation)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation really helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combinations` from `itertools` module, that can create a list of tuples, not a list of lists:

```
from itertools import combinations
# Generate all the combinations of 0 and 1
# in a list of tuples where each tuple is formed by 10 elements
# Which leads to 184756 combinations
gen_list = combinations([0,1]*10, 10)
# remove duplicates
unique_elements = list(set(gen_list))
# len(unique_elements)
# >>> 1024
```

An overview of the created list:

```
>>> unique_elements
[
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
...
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand the part about the 184756 combinations and duplicates. Could you explain that?

Comment: `combinations([0,1]*10, 10)` will create a lot of duplicates there will be 184756 whithin this operation. This is why i'm using `set()` to remove the duplicates then turing the set to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `numpy` for this. For array creation, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
rows, cols = 1024, 10
arr = np.zeros((rows, cols))
```

Now, for setting certain values to 1 based on your condition, this could be used:

```
# this should be changed based on your needs
arr[arr > 0] = 1 # set all values greater than 0 to 1
```

If you need to create an array initialized with random binary data, you could do:

```
arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(rows,cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't a concern, you could always count from 0 to 1023, create the string representation of that number in base 2 then convert to a list.

```
def binary_cols(n_cols):
    for i in range(2**n_cols):
        k = [int(j) for j in "{:b}".format(i)]
        k = [0]*(n_cols - len(k)) + k
        yield k
```

for col in binary_cols(10):
    print col

gives

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
...
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]    

print(len(list(binary_cols(10))))
1024
```

---

edit: I've just noticed that my answer is essentially a duplicate of Saleh Hindi's. Leaving mine here as there is a big enough difference in the specific tools used for the task, but their answer has a better explanation.

Comment: I didn't ever realise that creating the string representation in binary was a possibility. But since I'm a biologist and I need this to run a genetics simulation, I think computational expenses might be an issue. Thank you so much tho!